# When exporting a Java Scala project it failed to get scala/ScalaObject

Tags: java, windows, scala, noclassdeffounderror, scala-ide

I'm working on eclipse with Scala 2.9.3 plugin installed.
I have a Scala project which work fine from the eclipse but when I export the project to "Runnable JAR File" and  I try to run it I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
```

I tried all the 3 Library handling options:

- Extract required libraries...
- Package required libraries...
- Copy required libraries...

All end up in the same exception.

What I need to do in order to make a standalone JAR file from my project?

Comment: Are you sure scala-library.jar is amongst the jars?

Comment: @pedrofurla: I'm not sure how to check it (new to Java world). but I guess it exists somewhere since it's running from the Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin in the past, I found it quite easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SBT for maintaining & building your project, then like `pedrofurla` suggested you should try [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin. In the simplest case just add the follwing to your project build (i prefer `Build.scala`, but in `*.sbt` it looks the same):

1) imports:

```
import sbtassembly.Plugin._
import AssemblyKeys._
```

2) settings:

```
mainClass in assembly := Some("path.to.MainClass")
jarName   in assembly := "jar-name.jar"
```

3) If you want to publish artifact:

```
artifact in (Compile, assembly) ~= { art =>
  art.copy(`classifier` = Some("assembly"))
} // add classifier
```

and then your publishing task:

```
lazy val publishingSettings = addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, assembly), assembly) ++ Seq(
    publishTo := /* your repository settings */
  )
```

The call `assembly` to get all-in-one jar-file or publish to publish it to your repo. That should work

Comment: I maybe missing something, that may be because I used to the C, C++ and C# family. But what the point of Scala if I can't use it to make something which will run outside of Eclipse unless I download more plugins and change the build definitions manually?

Comment: I'm sure that you can, I just don't know how to assemble a project within Eclipse, cause i'm working with IDEA with sbt-plugin. And the way how you r building/assembling your project has nothing to do with the language itself