# Code not compiling (Eclipse Scala IDE)

Tags: scala, noclassdeffounderror, scala-ide

If I create a new Scala project in the Eclipse Scala IDE, my code compiles and runs. However, when I import an existing project, my code doesn't compile (no class files are generated) and I get a NoClassDefFoundError in the console. Any ideas what could cause this? Do I need additional software?

Comment: Classically it means [there are some jar missing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17773595/298389) -- it may be either one of your dependencies or scala-lib.jar itself. The reason depends on the actual NCDFE error message -- put it there so we could say you proper option.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem; apparently, there were remaining problems in other projects and since the original project depended on this, these needed to be fixed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591166/code-not-compiling-eclipse-scala-ide#comment29078652_19591166), this is often the symptom of missing dependencies in your imported project, either jars or other projects (which should be imported and buildable in the IDE).